# Map is not loading on the page using load()

Tags: google-maps, jquery

I have the Google map in my page. when i refresh the page the map is loading. But the problem is when i load the page using load() the map only is not working.
I get the latitude and longitude from php.

```
var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $propertyValues->lat; ?>, <?php echo $propertyValues->lng; ?>);
                                                var mapOptions = {
                                                  center: fenway,
                                                  zoom: 16,

                                                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                                };

                                                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
                                                var image = '<?php echo $path;?>components/com_propertylist/images/Home.png';

                                                var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                    position: fenway,
                                                    map: map,
                                                    icon: image
                                                });
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: we need to see some of your code to help with this problem

Comment: When you say 'the map is not working', is it that the map is completely greyed out and you can't work with it? or is there not even the 'grey' and it just remains completely uninvoked?

Comment: the map is completely grey out